# Spring Boot upgrade, set-cooike header not passed from ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring-boot, httpresponse

I'm trying to upgrade Spring Boot from `1.3.8.RELEASE` to `1.4.0.RELEASE`
after the upgrade, the `Set-Cookie` headers are NOT passed to the browser

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public HttpEntity<Result> postRequest( @RequestBody RequestObject r ){
    Result body = getBody(r);
    HttpHeader header = getHeader(); //contains Set-Cookie
    return new ResponseEntity(body,header,Httpstatus.OK)
}
```

I read around I found this alternative solution which works but requires me to change the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public HttpEntity<Result> postRequest( @RequestBody RequestObject r, HttpServletResponse httpResponse ){
    Result body = getBody(r);
    HttpHeader header = getHeader(); //contains Set-Cookie foo=bar
    response.addCookie(new Cookie("foo", "bar"));
    return new ResponseEntity(body,header,Httpstatus.OK)
}
```

However, there are many many controllers and I don't like to change every single one. Is there a new Security Feature in the newer Spring Boot that I'm not aware of so I could turn off/on to make the old code work throughout the project?

I really don't want to change over 500 controllers...

NOTE: Other Headers that are not `Set-Cookie` get passed through.

Comment: Are you sure the header is not being sent to the client (have you tried to request your resource with e.g. curl)? Have you tried to debug if the header is being set correctly, if it will be overridden or what else causes your setting to be ignored?

Comment: @Smutje we have a set of E2E that checks headers been passed, all the E2E were passing before the upgrade to 1.4.0, now they are failing as a result of not having Set-Cookie. (I've also done debug/curl and other manual checks)

Comment: Yes, but I guess/hope the Spring guys do not manually ignore/blacklist the "Set-Cookie" header explicitely on serializing a response, so I guess the value is being overridden somehow - at least I hope.

Comment: @Smutje Couldn't agree more. However, this is the current behavior that I'm seeing.  Only thing I could think is a new "security" feature that disallows Set-Cookie to be passed via header. if that's the case then there should be a way to disable it. Still reading through it.

Comment: Fair enough, but my experiences with Spring are rather bleak concerning the amount of their documentation so I started debugging instead of trying to understand their intentions... ;-)

Comment: I found an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20504) that could be related. If so, updating the spring-framework version to 4.3.12 (or the last one 4.3.24) could solve the problem.

Comment: @vanOekel It looks as if that's indeed the problem, lemme try to play around with it and will post the results

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding your "set-cookie" header to the list of exposed headers, which should be accessible by the browser.

Example-

```
HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
responseHeaders.setHeader({your header name}, {value of header}); //set your header

//add the header names you want to expose to a list 
List<String> allowedHeaders = new ArrayList<>();
allowedHeaders.add({your header name});           

//add the list of headers to be exposed to the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header
responseHeaders.put("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", allowedHeaders);
```

Comment: Do I need to do this for every controller? as mentioned, as long as I add set-cookie directly to HttpServerletResponse then it works, but I have to do this for every controller.

Comment: This won't work if the header does not even reach the client.